# Как правильно считать properties через Apache Commons CLI?

Tags: java, cmd

Через командную строку с помощью **-D** приложение должно получать параметры, например, такие `-Dtest="true"` или `-Dmyarray="one,two,five"` (не помню, как правильно указывать multiple-значения). Причем возможных параметров очень много, по-отдельности проверять каждое с помощью `System.getProperty(...)` - не вариант, мне нужно просто добавить их в заполненный `PropertiesConfiguration` (от Apache Commons), для которого уже написана логика (если будут конфликты, то приоритет за пропертями из командной строки).

Как это сделать с помощью **Apache Commons CLI**? Не нашел подходящих примеров в сети.

Comment: если слишком много, может стоит рассмотреть вариант чтения из `conf.properties` ?

Comment: @Senior Automator тут смысл в том, что возможных параметров много, из них использоваться будут лишь несколько, а какие именно - неизвестно. Из файла пропертей уже реализовано чтение, но часть параметров нужно переопределить прямо из командной строки

Comment: ты считываешь из файла, если из командной строки есть такой же параметр, то замени, если нет. то оставь тот из файла. все зависит от количества параметров, до 10-15 еще можно передать, а больше не имеет смысла. System.getProperty(...) почему не вариант ?

Comment: @Senior Automator а, точняк, что-то тупанул, в принципе норм подход )) но что если в cmd зададут параметр, которого не будет в файле...

Comment: читаем из файла, далее приоритет параметрам, если есть уже такой - заменяем. если нету - добавляем новый, далее из окружения по такому же принципу. главнее с приоритетами разобраться. я предлагаю файл - окружение - параметры